# SSLv3 communications in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ssl

I would like to know if Iphone OS supports SSLv3 network communications ?
Are there any tutorial or how to on the web ? I didn't find anything about this!
Which framework/library should I use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about SSL in general (and not a specific version of SSL), then yes.  The `NSURLConnection` supports https URLs.  Just follow the standard docs on opening a connect with `NSURLConnection` but specify the URL with the scheme `https://`.